# AngularJS service is undefined inside directive link function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm following [John Papa's Angular 1 conventions](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md) and I'm trying to implement a custom directive which needs to use the angular service called `$parse` in the link function, but the service seems to be unavailable.

When the `uiSalesTotalDashboard` function is invoked the service is available, but when the link function is invoked the service seems to be undefined?

```
(function() {
   'use strict';
   module.exports = uiDirectives.directive('uiSalesTotalDashboard', uiSalesTotalDashboard);
   uiSalesTotalDashboard.$inject = ['$parse'];

   function uiSalesTotalDashboard($parse) {
       // $parse is available
       var directive = {
           scope: {
               salesPeriods: '@',
               translations: '@'
           },
           link: link,
           restrict: 'E',
           templateUrl: '/Scripts/app/shared/ui/templates/sales-total-dashboard.html'
       };
       return directive;

       function link(scope, element, attrs) {
           // $parse is undefined
       }
   }
})();
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Could you create a fiddle to reproduce it?

Comment: The variable cannot be defined in one point and undefined in another. What were your reasons to think that it is? If you inspected it with a debugger, the latter was wrong on that.

Comment: @estus it was indeed the debugger that showed the wrong data. When  I didn't use the $parse service inside the link function, chrome debugger would show that the $parse service was undefined. But if I declared the $parse inside the link function the chrome debugger showed it correctly. So this must be a chrome debugger bug. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your code, it is unclear, coz u did not show your angular module definition or I feel something wrong.
Following code works. Try to find what is the difference. Don't worry about controller part, I added it just to make sure my sample code works :). Thanks

```js
angular.module('sample', [])
  .controller('sampleController', ['$scope',function($scope){
    $scope.title= 'I am sample controller';
  }])
  .directive('uiSalesTotalDashboard', uiSalesTotalDashboard);
  
  uiSalesTotalDashboard.$inject = ['$parse'];
  function uiSalesTotalDashboard($parse) {
       var directive = {
           scope: {
               salesPeriods: '@',
               translations: '@'
           },
           link: link,
           restrict: 'E',
           template: '<p>I am directive</p'
       };
       return directive;

       function link(scope, element, attrs) {
           // $parse is working in this code
            console.log('----Printing $parse : ---');
           console.log($parse);
       }
   }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="sample">
  <head>
    <title>My AngularJS App</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="sampleController">
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    <ui-sales-total-dashboard></ui-sales-total-dashboard>
  </body>
</html>
```